# set different color on click function in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to change color our button are Press then canvas inside text color change.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.font = '48px serif';
context.fillStyle = 'red'; // sets text color to red
context.fillText('Example text', 20, 65);

function ChangeColor() {
  console.log("dd", context);
  context.fillStyle = "blue";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #my-canvas {
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="my-canvas" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
  <br>
  <button onClick="ChangeColor()"> Change Font Color Blue</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a question here? Don't forget to ask one so it's clear exactly what you need. You'll need to clear and redraw the canvas in your callback. Simply changing a context property doesn't trigger a rerender or change the pixels already rendered to the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the canvas and redraw everything using the `"blue"` color.

You can clear the canvas using

```js
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Here a working example for your use case:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

draw("red");

function ChangeColor() {
  clearCanvas();
  draw("blue");
}

function clearCanvas() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function draw(color) {
  context.font = '48px serif';
  context.fillStyle = color; // sets text color to whatever was passed in
  context.fillText('Example text', 20, 65);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #my-canvas {
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="my-canvas" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
  <br>
  <button onClick="ChangeColor()"> Change Font Color Blue</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest code I can come up with is to move the drawing to a function and have the color as a parameter, that way we can call it directly from the button click event, see sample code below

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.font = '48px serif';

function draw(color) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.fillStyle = color; 
  context.fillText('Example text', 20, 65);
  context.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 15);
}

draw('red')
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
<br>
<button onClick="draw('blue')">Draw Blue</button>
<button onClick="draw('black')">Draw Black</button>
<button onClick="draw('yellow')">Draw Yellow</button>
```

---

Another simple option using `setInterval` to allow for an animated canvas
we set the `fillStyle` in the button click event

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.font = '48px serif';
context.fillStyle = 'red';
x = 0

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   
  context.fillText('Example text', 20, 65);
  context.fillRect(x++ % 80, Math.sin(x/3)*8, 200, 15);
}

setInterval(draw, 50)
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
<br>
<button onClick="context.fillStyle = 'blue'">Draw Blue</button>
<button onClick="context.fillStyle = 'black'">Draw Black</button>
<button onClick="context.fillStyle = 'yellow'">Draw Yellow</button>
```